# Fetch a whole row from SQL Server with PowerShell

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell

So I use `ExecuteScalar()` to get one value from a table. But how can I get multiple values, i.e. values from multiple columns.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DB_Name; Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$query = "select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1= x;" 
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$NewBatchID = $command.ExecuteScalar() 
$connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method, using .NET objects in PowerShell, is with a [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter). This can load multiple rows and columns into a `DataTable` for subsequent use.

This example assumes a single row is returned:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DB_Name; Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$query = "select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1= x;"

$sqlDataAdapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($query, $connectionString)
$dataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable
[void]$sqlDataAdapter.Fill($dataTable)
$col1 = $dataTable.Rows[0]["col1"]
$col2 = $dataTable.Rows[0]["col2"]
$col3 = $dataTable.Rows[0]["col3"]
```

Comment: Thanks, one of the columns is a `time` type and PowerShell is splitting is up into its parts. Is it possible to keep the original format?

Comment: A SQL time returns a .NET Timespan, IIRC. You can use `ToString()` to get the value formatted as hours, minutes, seconds. fractional seconds: `$col1.ToString()` or use the Timespan properties individually, like `$col1.Hours`.

Comment: Don't I need to write `$dataTable.Close()` in the end?

Comment: And how come you don't have a `$dataTable.Open()`? The code works just wondering...

Comment: @David, the `SqlDataAdapter` takes care of the low-level plumbing and processing. It instantiates a connection object using the specified connection string, creates a command object with the specified query, opens the connection, executes the query with ExecuteReader, loads the data table with SqlDataReader.Read() and finally closes the connection. You could do it all yourself like the code in the answer from @PalleDue.

Comment: The examples in Books online use C# and the syntax seems a bit different... How do I know which parts of the syntax are applicable to PowerShell. I think I understand what the .Net framework is... Can you help a bit with general advice on learning .Net. In powerShell often it seems you can either do it the PowerShell way or the .Net way...

Comment: The syntax one uses for the same .NET objects varies by language. Being familiar with C#, I tend to use the C#-like syntax, such as `$sqlDataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($query, $connectionString)`. You can even throw a semi-colon at the end for eye candy ;-)

Comment: One note is that one needs to invoke static methods and properties differently in PS, by enclosing the class name followed by 2 colons. For example, `[DateTime]::Now` instead of DateTime::Now like one would in C#. A lot takes getting used to compared to a compiled .NET language.

Comment: Hi. So now I want to get a column. It seems to works without the last four lines... What does the `void` line do?

Comment: The [void] just ignores the result of the `Fill` method (number of rows). The powershell way to do the same thing is to pipe the result to `Out-Null`. I don't know what you mean by "seems to work without the last four lines" since no query is executed until `Fill` is invoked and the `DataTable` will be empty.

Comment: Sorry I guess I had ran `fill` too the first time. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to put data from an ODBC source in a DataTable? i.e. when my connection is created as `$con = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection $connStr
$con.Open()
$sql = "SELECT col FROM table"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand ($sql, $con)`

Comment: @xhr489, yes. Instead of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter`, use the equivalent object of the `System.Data.Odbc` namespace object `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter` and change the connection string for the ODBC driver you are using (keywords vary by driver). SQL Server example (e.g. "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=ServerName;Database=DB_Name;Trusted_Connection=Yes").

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to close or commit the connection for `$sqlDataAdapter`? Or does that happen automatically? The answer bellow has a close method.

Comment: @xhr489, no need to close when you let the adapter manage the connection (as with the connection string specification). [The doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.8#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable)) says if the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed"

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to work with the DataTable as a DataFrame e.g. as in Python and R or do I always have to loop through the DataTable?

Comment: @xhr489, you don't necessarily need to code looping constructs in PowerShell. For example, you can show the contents of the data type with `$dataTable | Format-List` or `$dataTable | Out-GridView`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a DataReader:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DB_Name; Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$query = "select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1= x;" 
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()

$dataReader = $command.ExecuteReader()
$fieldCount = $dataReader.FieldCount
while ($dataReader.Read()) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $fieldCount; $i++) 
    {
        Write-Host "$($dataReader.GetName($i)) is $($dataReader.GetValue($i))." 
    }
}

$connection.Close()
```

Personally I dislike both SqlDataAdapter and DataReaders because of all the boilerplate code. I think it should have been done in a more elegant way.